# How do you measure the effect of branch misprediction?

Tags: c++, branch

I'm currently profiling an implementation of binary search. Using some special instructions to measure this I noticed that the code has about a 20% misprediction rate. I'm curious if there is any way to check how many cycles I'm potentially losing due to this. It's a MIPS based architecture.

Comment: The funny thing is that with a binary search you would expect close a 50% mispredictions on whether the searched value is greater or smaller the the element being compared. I assume that getting only a 20% is due to other conditional expressions (checking pointers before transversing in a tree? or balancing the tree?). I don't think that 20% is a big misprediction rate for a basically random choice.

Comment: True enough but anything helps on a 300mhz system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look it up in the docs for your CPU. If you can't find this information specifically, the length of the CPU's pipeline is a fairly good estimate.

Given that it's MIPS and it's a 300MHz system, I'm going to guess that it's a fairly short pipeline. Probably 4-5 stages, so a cost of 3-4 cycles per mispredict is probably a reasonable guess.

Answer (score 4):

You're losing 0.2 * N cycles per iteration, where N is the number of cycles that it takes to flush the pipelines after a mispredicted branch. Suppose N = 10 then that means you are losing 2 clocks per iteration on aggregate. Unless you have a *very* small inner loop then this is probably not going to be a significant performance hit.

Comment: Well ... if you have lots of 20% mispredicted branches per iteration the time could start to add up ;)

Comment: @Goz: yes, good point - I guess when I say *loop* or *iteration* I really mean a block with one partly predictable branch in it, but there could be more than one such block in a loop.

Comment: Thats the thing. cycles add up fast and are more precious when you only have 300 million a second.

Answer (score 1):

On an in-order CPU you may be able to calculate the approximate mispredict cost as a product of the number of mispredicts and the mispredict cost (which is generally a function of some part of the pipeline)

On a modern [out-of-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) CPU, however, such a general calculation is usually not possible. There may be a large number of instructions in flight<sup>1</sup>, only some of which are flushed by a misprediction. The surrounding code may be latency bound by one or more chains of dependent instructions, or it may be throughput bound on resources like execution units, renaming throughput, etc, or it may be somewhere in-between.

On such a core, the penalty per misprediction is very difficult to determine, even with the help of performance counters. You can find [entire papers](http://tianna1121.qiniudn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/2006-Eyerman-1.pdf) dedicated to the topic: that one found a penalty size of ranging from 9 to 35 cycles averaged across entire benchmarks: if you look at some small piece of code the range will be even larger: a penalty of zero is easy to demonstrate, and you could create a scenario where the penalty is in the 100s of cycles.

Where does that leave you, just trying to determine the misprediction cost in your binary search? Well a simple approach is just to control the number of mispredictions and measure the difference! If you set up your benchmark input have a range of behavior, starting with always following the same branch pattern, all the way to having a random pattern, you can plot the misprediction count versus runtime degradation. If you do, share your result!

---

<sup>1</sup>*Hundreds* of instructions in-flight in the case of modern big cores such as those offered by the x86, ARM and POWER architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your specs for that info and if that fails, run it a billion times and time it external to your program (stop watch of something.)  Then run it with without a miss and compare.